# how to set div height auto grow with content having padding style

Tags: html, css

The problem I have is the div height is not grow, so my label block the other element on my page. I know I can set the height for div. But I want grow automatically. How can I do that?

Thank you!

```
<div id="div">
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Label" />
</div>

#lbl
{
    padding: 1em;
}
#div
{
    //What I should do here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give a particular height for that div when content is more then enough for that div it will automatically increase the height.

```
#div
{
    min-height:give specific height;
}
```

Comment: I found that I have to set the padding for #div

Answer (score 3):

Add this to #div: `height:auto; overflow:hidden;`

Comment: I tried that, the height is not growing, but cut the head and tail of my label